# How can I set the value of an uninitialised pointer in a function in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

I'm currently doing an assignment in C and it's the first time that I've really had to understand pointers.  I'm mostly getting the hang of it, but it's thrown me into the deep end (at least in my eyes), and I'm having trouble with one situation.

I have a pointer to a struct `structPtr`, which contains a pointer `headPtr` to a head node of a linked list ((*headPtr).nextNode etc.).

Now I'm adding nodes to this list through a function, however my issue is that when I first set the head node, I can only manage to do it with `(*structPtr).headPtr = &newNode`.  But this is within the function, and testing seems to tell me that after the function finishes, &newNode is dumped.  I'm wanting to do `(*(*structPtr).headPtr) = newNode`, but this results in a segmentation fault, even if I set `(*structPtr).headPtr = NULL`.

Any guidance?

Comment: I would assume you haven't allocated memory for structPtr, but show us the code

Comment: @Salgar it appears you were right.  Sorry there was a bit of code to show, and so I settled with a (very) basic summary instead.  It seems to have worked regardless.

Comment: C has the builtin syntax of the `->` for `(*X).Y` to be written as `X->Y`. This is what people visually expect when they read C code.

Comment: @JensGustedt I've been seeing that symbol around but thought it may have just been for C++.  Ok I'll try use that from now on, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use pointers to local variables if the pointer is used outside of the function. All local variables are on the stack, and that part of the stack is reclaimed when a function returns, and will be reused for the next function call.

You need to dynamically allocate the structures inside the function, using e.g. [`malloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc):

```
structPtr->headPtr = malloc(sizeof(*structPtr->headPtr));
```

Don't forget to [`free`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) the mermory when you're done with it.

Comment: That's great - I've managed to access a value in *headPtr outside of the function, so looks like it's working.  I used that line of code you provided followed by the (*(*structPtr).headPtr) = newNode I was previously wanting to do.  It crashes shortly afterwards though, which might be from some other bug caused by this bit of code actually working right.  Let me track done this bug before I mark your answer as correct.

Comment: it was crashing because you were trying to access something which was not yours.Now you are asking for memory before accessing it after implementing Joachim's idea :)

Comment: Yep I think I see the need for it.  Though my next bit seems to not need it, even though it's again setting a new variable inside a function.  Perhaps having that one node manually set enables me to not worry about the rest of the linked list.

Comment: Actually it looks like I do need it - my linked list now composes of the original head node, and the last added node.